# Setting corner radius through viewDidAppear() or viewWillLayoutSubviews()?

Tags: swift, uibutton, rounded-corners, cornerradius

In summary, setting the corner radii to get round left and right edges for my UIButtons in my application works by grabbing the buttons bounds and dividing the height by two in viewWillLayoutSubviews(). However, if I navigate to another screen via UIBarButtonItem(), rotate the device, and then navigate back to the screen with the UIButtons() they are NOT round. The corner radii are still based on the button dimensions from the previous orientaion. I tried to use viewDidAppear, but there is a second/noticable delay in setting the corner radii.

Is there anyway to speed the process up of viewDidAppear? I don't think viewWillAppear will work because the view controller isn't aware of the default (square) dimensions of the uibutton(s) I am changing.

The application I am working on is this:

[Screenshots of my current application from loading screen to the point of the corner radius not being updated correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4auL6.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) instead, because you'll have the updated bounds at that point, but not yet in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Or I might suggesting have a button subclass that does the rounding within its own [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews), freeing your view controller from having to iterate through buttons and rounding them.

For example:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }

}
```

And then just use this class instead of `UIButton`. That yields:

[image]

Comment: I tried using viewDidLayoutSubviews and was still unsuccessful. I am going to try and look into layoutSubviews here shortly. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Sweet! This resolved the answer to this question! However, I implemented the method inside an extension I had for UIButton flash animations. Would you happen to know why calling layoutSubviews inside of an extension would remove all of my setAttributedTitle 's?

Comment: My setAttributedTitles are set in viewDidLoad, but when I implement UIButton.layoutSubviews() the titles do not display.

Comment: You really shouldn't be overriding any methods (such as `layoutSubviews`) within an extension of the base class. You don't really want to be changing the behavior of a class. If you do this in a subclass, you shouldn't be seeing this sort of behavior.

Comment: Okay, so I need to sub class it and not implement it into an extension? I should of pointed out I am still relatively new to Swift and programming in general.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. Subclass, not extension.

Comment: Would you mind pointing me in the right direction of how to go about subclassing the UIButtons of a specific view controller? I have learned quite a bit of how subclassing works through the following link: [https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html] . However, `layoutSubviews()` doesnt seem to be a member of my view controller I am using as my superclass to my subclass of RoundedButtons.

Comment: @TonyPendleton - The code, in its entirety, is shown in my answer. All you have to do is go to your storyboard and set the base class for your buttons to be `RoundedButton`. Or if you're programmatically creating buttons, use `RoundedButton` instead of `UIButton`. The only thing at all sophisticated here is if you include the `@IBDesignable` qualifier so that you can see the button rendered right in Interface Builder. If you google "swift @ibdesignable example" you'll probably find lots of nice discussions on the concept. (Or just remove the `@IBDesignable` if that's too confusing.)

Comment: You are correct! I figured it out just an hour ago before seeing this. It was such an an easy fix. I really appreciate your help. I will do more reading up on these topics but I was able to get it working doing everything you said.