# UIButtons setAttributedTitle Disappears After Calling layoutSubviews in UIButton Extension

Tags: swift, subclass, viewdidload, layoutsubviews

I had a corner radius problem with all of my UIButtons, but was finally able to resolve the issue by following the solution at ([Setting corner radius through viewDidAppear() or viewWillLayoutSubviews()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971385/setting-corner-radius-through-viewdidappear-or-viewwilllayoutsubviews)
) However, now I have "lost" all of my attributed button titles. I have been battling this issue for a couple of weeks and feel like I am very close to figuring it all out. I apologize if this is a poorly phrased question as I am still relatively new to Swift.

Here is the application I am working on:
[my default iOS calculator project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4auL6.jpg)

In my Swift-file, UIButtonExtension.swift, I have the following:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIButton {
   override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        layer.cornerRadius = radius

    }
}
```

In one of my other Swift-files, myCalculatorViewController.swift, I have:

```
import UIKit

class myCalculatorViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tag1_Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tag2_Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tag3_Button: UIButton!
//     .....
@IBOutlet weak var tag19_Button: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// main/basic calc button view controller

tag1_Button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
tag1_Button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
tag1_Button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
let str_tag1_Button = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "AC")
str_tag1_Button.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10), range: NSMakeRange(0, 2))    
str_tag1_Button.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), range: NSMakeRange(0, 2))
tag1_Button.setAttributedTitle(str_tag1_Button, for: .normal) 
tag1_Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 40/255.0, green: 247/255.0, blue: 45/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

// and so forth with the rest of the tag buttons up to tag19_Button that sets title, "="

}
}
```

Next, in another Swift-file, instantiatedLandscapeButtonViewController, I have a similiar setup for the UIButtons with tag1 to tag30:

```
import UIKit

class instantiatedLandscapeButtonViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var tag1_Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tag2_Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tag3_Button: UIButton!
//     .....
@IBOutlet weak var tag30_Button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// additional landscape buttons, setup

tag1_Button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
tag1_Button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
tag1_Button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
let str_tag1_Button = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "mc")
str_tag1_Button.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10), range: NSMakeRange(0, 2))
str_tag1_Button.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor(red: 251/255.0, green: 251/255.0, blue: 251/255.0, alpha: 1.0), range: NSMakeRange(0, 2))
tag1_Button.setAttributedTitle(str_tag1_Button, for: .normal)

// and so forth

}




}
```

Comment: You need to post some code, because your question doesn't explain your problem in enough detail.

Comment: Okay, I did. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: But now it's still unclear what the problem is. You show some code configuring some buttons: then what happens?

Comment: What does "lost my attributed titles" even mean, exactly?

Comment: I lost the setAttributedTitles I set for the UIButtons. I have working corner radii for all of the buttons, but now they show no titles. They are blank/lost. I am trying to look into how to subclass this because I think that will resolve the issue.

Comment: Well that's certainly what my answer advises you to do, and you must do something like that in any case; you cannot `override` in an `extension`.

Comment: Also, what gives your buttons size? If they are not large enough to accommodate the title, it will be suppressed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really not following. I know the button sizes will fit the attributed text I am displaying with the font size of 10. I somehow need to figure out how to set/add the attributed text to the uibuttons after layoutSubviews is called/implemented.

Comment: Well, in my answer I've shown you some code that works.

Comment: Also make sure to set the type of the button to be `.custom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as it stands is dangerous and illegal:

```
extension UIButton {
   override open func layoutSubviews() {
```

No! You cannot perform an `override` in an `extension`! The results can be unpredictable. The way to achieve a reliable circular button is to *subclass* UIButton, where `override` *is* legal, and use that subclass.

```
class MyCircularButton: UIButton {
    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
}
```

Now use a MyCircularButton instead of a plain UIButton wherever you want a circular button. I don't know that this will solve the issue you're having, but it is certainly a required first step.

I tested your remaining code like this, and it worked fine:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tag1_Button = MyCircularButton()
        tag1_Button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 40, height: 40)
        tag1_Button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        tag1_Button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
        tag1_Button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
        let str_tag1_Button = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "AC")
        str_tag1_Button.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10), range: NSMakeRange(0, 2))
        str_tag1_Button.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), range: NSMakeRange(0, 2))
        tag1_Button.setAttributedTitle(str_tag1_Button, for: .normal)
        tag1_Button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 40/255.0, green: 247/255.0, blue: 45/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.view.addSubview(tag1_Button)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: But of course, as I say in my other comment, you must make sure the button is large enough to display the title.

Comment: I'm going ahead and setting this as the solution. Is your example code creating the UIButton programmatically? I have mine setup as an IBOutlet.                                  Anyways, thank you for all of the help Matt. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You can see what my solution is doing, but the use of the outlet won't make any difference. You have to make sure, of course, that the button _in the storyboard_ is an instance of the subclass, not a simple UIButton.